# RewriteRule to localhost results in redirects being relative to localhost rather than original URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, reverse-proxy

I have a backend server running correctly and bound to `127.0.0.1:5000`.

In the `.htaccess` in my site's root directory, I have `RewriteRule "^(.*)$" http://localhost:5000/$1 [P,NE,L,QSA]` to redirect requests to my server.

If I visit the home page of my site `https://example.com`, I get redirected to `localhost:5000/login` rather than `https://example.com/login`.

I have tried suggestions to use `ProxyPass`/`ProxyPassReverse` but as I only have access to `.htaccess` (lots of sites run on this server), these don't work.

Is there a way for me to pass the originally requested URL to my server so that it replies appropriately? Or can I add something to `.htaccess` to rewrite redirects appropriately before they are returned to the client?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this rule to proxy all of your requests using `HTTP_HOST` variable:

```bash
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}:5000%{REQUEST_URI} [P,NE,L]
```

Comment: This doesn't connect me to my backend server. The apache logs say `[proxy:error] [pid 995198] (111)Connection refused: AH00957: HTTP: attempt to connect to [ipv6addr]:5000 (*) failed` where `ipv6addr` is one of the addresses returned by `ip address` in the line `inet6 ipv6addr scope global deprecated`. I tried binding my backend server to ::1 (as this appears to be the equivalent of 127.0.0.1), but got the same result.

Comment: So did you try: `RewriteRule ^ http:///example.com:5000%{REQUEST_URI} [P,NE,L]` ?

Comment: Yes, that doesn't work with the same error. I assume because I am only binding to `127.0.0.1:5000`, it isn't accessible externally and so the only way to get through is internally with either `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` in the `RewriteRule` statement. 

Using `0.0.0.0` isn't an option with this machine unfortunately.

Comment: So you mean `RewriteRule ^ http://localhost:5000%{REQUEST_URI} [P,NE,L]` works fine?

Comment: It works in the sense that the request is successfully passed to the backend, but then the backend tries to redirect me to `/login` and the URL in my browser changes to `http://localhost:5000/login` which obviously won't work (I want it go to `http://example.com/login` using the original URL rather than the rewritten one)

Comment: That means backend needs to be fixed. It should just have internal forward to `/login` but an external redirect.